# SASS group parent selector

Tags: sass, nested, styles

I have this code:

```
.sibling-class {
    .some-class1 {...}
    .some-class2 {...}
    .some-class3 {...}
    ....
    .some-class1000 {...}
}
```

And I need:

```
.sibling-class {
    &.some-class1 {...}
    &.some-class2 {...}
    &.some-class3 {...}
    ....
    &.some-class1000 {...}
}
```

How can I do it without putting `&` one thousand times?
Is there some group syntax for this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [@for](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while) loop:

```
.sibling-class {

  @for $i from 1 through 1000 {
    &.some-class#{$i} {
      …
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You could for the sake of using a @for loop put all the unique rules into a Sass map and then iterate 1000 times - but either way you would have to manually enter those unique rules/values. Perhaps putting that `&` a thousand times is the lesser evil here.

Comment: If those 1000 classes are not create on fly, I absolutely agree with Trollsyn! :-)

Comment: Bad news, but thank you Trollsyn. I hope the syntax will be improved one day )